# Regex negative lookahead string with special character python

Tags: python, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

It's about content dimensions on a website. This [link checker tool](https://wummel.github.io/linkchecker/) supports Python Regex. With the link checker I want to get information about just one content dimension.

I'd like to match all except the one with the string `de_de` (for the `--no-follow-url` option).

```
https://www.example.com/int_en
https://www.example.com/int_de
https://www.example.com/de_de  ##should not match or all others should match
https://www.example.com/be_de
https://www.example.com/fr_fr
https://www.example.com/gb_en
https://www.example.com/us_en
https://www.example.com/ch_de
https://www.example.com/ch_it
https://www.example.com/shop
```

I'm stuck somewhere inbetween these approaches:

```
https:\/\/www.example.com\/\bde\_de
https:\/\/www.example.com\/[^de]{2,3}[^de]
https:\/\/www.example.com\/[a-z]{2,3}\_[^d][^e]
https:\/\/www.example.com\/([a-z]{2,3}\_)(?!^de$)
https:\/\/www.example.com\/[a-z]{2,3}\_
https:\/\/www.example.com\/(?!^de\_de$)
```

How can I use a negative lookahead to match a string with a special character (underscore)? Can I go with something like

```
(?!^de_de$)
```

I'm new to regex, any help or input is appreciated.

Comment: every `/de_*` should not match or just `/de_de`?

Comment: Try `https:\/\/www.example.com\/(?!de_de(?:\/|$))[a-z-]+`

Comment: @Arman  de_de should not match, any other dimension should. I want /int_de, /de_en, /ch_de, /shop, ... to match for the --no-follow-url option.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It doesn't work, checked here: https://regex101.com/r/xiG2cJ/1

Comment: @SeviS. You do not know how to test at regex101. See [correct test](https://regex101.com/r/xiG2cJ/2). Always test in the target environment.

Comment: See [my final suggestion posted as an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47073044/3832970).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
https:\/\/www.example.com\/.+?(?<!de_de)\b
```

This matches:

```
https://www.example.com/shop
```

but not:

```
https://www.example.com/de_de
```

Pythex link [here](https://pythex.org/?regex=https%3A%5C%2F%5C%2Fwww.example.com%5C%2F.%2B%3F(%3F%3C!de_de)%5Cb&test_string=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fshop%20https%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com%2Fde_de%20&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)

Explanation: here we use a negative look behind `(?<!de_de)` applied to a word boundary (`\b`). This means that we have to find a word boundary not preceded by "de_de".

Answer (score 1):

Use the following regex:

```
https://www\.example\.com/(?!de_de(?:/|$))[a-z_]+
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/a3Z1FV/3).  If you also want to match `http`, add `s?` after `http` in the pattern, `https?://www\.example\.com/(?!de_de(?:/|$))[a-z_]+`.

Note you should escape the dots to match the real literal dots in the string. The `(?!de_de(?:/|$))[a-z_]+` part matches any 1+ letters/underscores (see `[a-z_]+`) that are not `de_de` that is followed with `/` or end of string.

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/3sJXAc):

```
import re
ex = ["https://www.example.com/int_en","https://www.example.com/int_de","https://www.example.com/de_de","https://www.example.com/be_de","https://www.example.com/de_en","https://www.example.com/fr_en","https://www.example.com/fr_fr","https://www.example.com/gb_en","https://www.example.com/us_en","https://www.example.com/ch_de","https://www.example.com/ch_it"]
rx = r"https://www\.example\.com/(?!de_de(?:/|$))[a-z_]+"
for s in ex:
    m = re.search(rx, s)
    if m:
        print("{} => MATCHED".format(s))
    else:
        print("{} => NOT MATCHED".format(s))
```

Output:

```
https://www.example.com/int_en => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/int_de => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/de_de => NOT MATCHED
https://www.example.com/be_de => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/de_en => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/fr_en => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/fr_fr => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/gb_en => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/us_en => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/ch_de => MATCHED
https://www.example.com/ch_it => MATCHED
```

Comment: I went with @gil.fernandes ' solution and added the ? to the https part. I didn't need python code, just the RegEx :) Still thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @SeviS Mind that [*that* regex may match something you do not expect](https://regex101.com/r/mBcm5c/2). Besides, there is no point escaping `/` in a Python regex.

Comment: I used this site https://regexr.com/ for testing, where the escaping was required since the site uses the browser's builtin regex syntax. Is it expected behaviour since the full stop `.` is "any single character"? I'll use escaping for the full stop in future, this is the right way I guess? https://regex101.com/r/mBcm5c/3 Thanks again.

Comment: @SeviS. Do not use regexr to test Python regexes, regexr only supports JavaScript regex syntax. To match a dot you must use `\.` inside the pattern.

Comment: Test regexps at https://regex101.com, but never rely on what that site produces, always test in the target environment.

Answer (score 0):

basically you want to exclude german versions of websites.
so I would go with smth like this:

```
import re
r = re.compile(r'(https?://|www\.)[^/]+/(?!de_de)\S+')
```

since it would also work for cases:

- https://example.com/de_de/news (links with further directories)
- http://www.example.com/ (http protocols)
- [www.example.com/de-de](https://example.com/de-de) (links lacking http/https prefixes)
- http://example.com/ (links lacking 'www' bit)